# akka-http complete response with different types

Tags: scala, akka-http

How can I complete akka-http response with different types based on future response?
I am trying to do something like

```
implicit val textFormat = jsonFormat1(Text.apply)
implicit val userFormat = jsonFormat2(User.apply)
 path(Segment) { id =>
              get {
                complete {
                  (fooActor ? GetUser(id)).map {
                    case n: NotFound => Text("Not Found")
                    case u: User => u
                  }
                }

              }
            }
```

but I am getting

```
type mismatch , expected: ToResponseMarshable , actual Futue[Product with Serializable ]
```

Comment: I think it is because it does not know how to unmarshall the custom `User` class. You have to define one. See the Unmarshaller section and links off this page: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/java/http/routing-dsl/marshalling.html

Comment: @brian I don't think so  since if I reply with User on both cases then it is OK, also not that I have unmarshaller in scope for User

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`onComplete`](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/routing-dsl/directives/future-directives/onComplete.html#oncomplete) directive:

```
get {
  path(Segment) { id =>
    onComplete(fooActor ? GetUser(id)) {
      case Success(actorResponse) => actorResponse match {
        case _ : NotFound => complete(StatusCodes.NotFound,"Not Found")
        case u : User => complete(StatusCodes.OK, u)
      }
      case Failure(ex) => complete(StatusCodes.InternalServerError, "bad actor")
    }
  }
}
```